# Übereinkommen vs. vereinbaren vs. einverstanden sein vs. sich einigen vs. sich absprechen vs. sich verständigen

Tags: meaning, verb, synonym, verb-usage, verb-choice

There are at least six verbs in German, which mean “to agree”:

- übereinkommen
- etw. vereinbaren
- einverstanden sein
- sich einigen / sich einig werden
- sich absprechen
- sich auf etw. verständigen

Can you please tell me what is the difference between all these verbs? Are they interchangeable? And most importantly, when should I choose one verb over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following are mostly synonymous and can be translated as "to agree on sth." in the sense of "to reach/come to an agreement", i.e. two or more parties had some kind of conflict/discussion/negotioation which they are resolving.

> übereinkommen
>   etw. vereinbaren
>   sich einigen / sich einig werden
>   sich auf etwas verständigen

The result - the sth. that the parties agree upon - may (but does not need to be) written down as a treaty/contract

> sich absprechen

has some overlap with this meaning, but it is usually used when the involved parties are discussing how to coordinate efforts on something.

> einverstanden sein

is different - by itself it does not say anything about the process of reaching an agreement, it merely states that the subject agrees to/concurs with something now, no matter if they always did so or were recently convinced.